# Two surface on android activity

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I create two surfaces in one FrameLayout.
My problem is that every surface works alone but when I want to run them in same time the screen is black.

I want to put every surface in half of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change FrameLayout to LinearLayout. Set a weight of 1 for each one and they will fill half of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView2"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```